# Problem downloading and using NOAA CCAP data

Tags: geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing

I am trying to download CCAP land cover data and would have expected .img or .tiff files, but the data downloads as a disk image file. I cannot figure out how to access/work with this file type. any help?

I want to use the data in R to create time series of land cover change in different basins.

Here is a link to download the data: https://coast.noaa.gov/ccapftp/#/
I am attempting to download the Virginia Regional Dates datasets

Comment: can you add the link you are trying to download from

Comment: How are you trying to use it? CCAP data can be opened in QGIS. Otherwise, you can convert it to a tiff (using GDAL) and use the color table in the disk image to know which classes (e.g. palustrine emergent vegetation) correspond to which pixel value. Tell us what you want to do and how you want to do it

Comment: I've just answered these questions in an edit.  Does this help?

Comment: @HeyBales this is useful information. Can you also add in what you have tried so far and what error messages you are getting? Are you using rGDAL?

Comment: I'm trying it now... I hadn't been able to sort out where to start until you mentioned GDAL, so this might actually solve my problem) (I'm quite new to remote sensing so I really appreciate the tip)

Comment: @HeyBales Take a look [here](https://www.neonscience.org/raster-data-r), this may help you get started

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to commentators above... the solution to this seems to be pretty straightforward. based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824853/large-img-file-processing-in-r-gis) and [here](https://www.neonscience.org/raster-data-r) :

It seems like the easiest way to convert ccap data to rasters in R is through the raster package ex:
`Land_cover <- raster("landcoverfile.img"`
and then later exporting the file as a .tiff

Leaving this up in case other beginners need help

Answer (score 0):

The NOAA C-CCAP data is served out in natively in ERDAS Imagine (.img) format and is available for download through the [NOAA: C-CAP FTP site](https://coast.noaa.gov/ccapftp/#/) by state and then year as you have already identified.

Additionally, the land cover data can be accessed through [NOAA's Data Access Viewer](https://coast.noaa.gov/dataviewer/#/landcover/search/) and alternatively be downloaded in other projections and GeoTIFF format. I work directly with the development of these datasets and happy to provide additional help as needed.

Cheers,

Brandon